set alias in output angular
I have recently implemented an Angular 17 project
I want to set a logical name for Output, but I can't and I get an error
This is the line of my code that gives an error to alias
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-btn',
  templateUrl: './custom-btn.component.html',
  styleUrl: './custom-btn.component.scss'
})
export class CustomBtnComponent {

  @Output({alias : 'onClick'}) clickBtnProject = new EventEmitter();

  clickBtn() {
    this.clickBtnProject.emit();
  }

}


The error texts are as follows
@Output decorator argument must resolve to a string Value is of type '{ alias: string }'.

__________________

Argument of type '{ alias: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)


Actually you can just give a string with a different name, that will be taken as an alias, Same name can also be provided!
Output Docs
@Output('onClick') clickBtnProject = new EventEmitter();


Hello, I followed your instructions, but I still have a problem
Error text: Output bindings should not be aliased (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-13)
